# Change width of select according to above div

Tags: jquery, javascript

i have got a message box, it should be displayed inside a select.
it should behave as if it is option of select. And also it should have right arrow of select

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>DivSelectWrapper</title>
    <style>
        #messageBox{
            position: absolute;
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: 50px;
        }
        .fancyListBox{
            position:relative;
        }
    </style>
    </head>

<body>
    <div class="fancyListBox">  
        <div id="messageBox">This is my message</div>
        <select id="select">
            <option>DD</option>
            <option>DAD</option>
            <option>DSD</option>
            <option>DWD</option>
            <option>DAD</option>
            <option>DRD</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" onClick="fChangeData()" text="testDivWrap"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok, if this is a game of 'hide the question', you win.

Comment: And your problem is...? You can't just expect that somebody does your job for free.